# Is slicing a queryset same as slicing the list used in __in clause? Can't understand this behavior

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a Story model which includes a TagField through django-tagging app.
I am fetching a list of stories for a particular tag. Functionally my code works fine, but I encountered a behavior which I can't quite understand.

Following code correctly gives me the list of stories as desired.

```
    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Story)
    ti = TaggedItem.objects.filter(tag__name='mobile',content_type=ct).values_list('object_id',flat=True)
    stories = Story.published_objects.filter(id__in=ti)
```

However, I wanted only first 50 stories. So what I did:

```
    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Story)
    ti = TaggedItem.objects.filter(tag__name='mobile',content_type=ct).values_list('object_id',flat=True)
    ti50 = ti[:50]
    stories = Story.published_objects.filter(id__in=ti50)
```

Here I am slicing the list itself to only hold 50 ids and then feeding the sliced list to __in clause. So I am expecting 50 stories in the list. However, I get this error instead:

```
   DatabaseError: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

I dont understand why is the `LIMIT` being used at MySQL though I am trying to slice it beforehand in Python itself.
Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not "slicing the list itself". `ti` is still a queryset, and the slice itself still doesn't evaluate it. So when you put it in the __in clause, it's still an object representing a unevaluated database query. Django tries to pass that as a subquery in the main Story query, but as the error message says, MySQL doesn't support that.

If you wanted to pass the 50 IDs, you have to explicitly evaluate the query by converting to a list:

```
ti50 = list(ti[:50])
```